# TypeOrm comparing comma delimited strings

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a nestjs api using typeorm and postgres where I need to query for any users that have the days 'Mo,Sa'. I am open to better ways of organizing the dayswillworkcolumn if a comma delimited string is not a good way to go about doing this.

| userId | name | dayswillwork |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | "Su,Mo,Tu" |
| 2 | Amber | "Fr,Sa,Su" |
| 3 | Craig | "Su,Tu,Th,Fr" |
| 4 | Steve | "Mo,Tu,We," |

I have tried...

```
query.where('employee.dayswillwork LIKE :days', {
        days: days,
      });
```

and...

```
query.where(":dayswillwork = ANY ( string_to_array(employee.dayswillwork , ','))", { dayswillwork : dayswillwork })
```

but neither one is returning anything.

Comment: look at the queries that each approach produces and try to manage that to select from the db what you need

Comment: "I am open to better ways of organizing the dayswillworkcolumn if a comma delimited string is not a good way to go about doing this." -- Hve a look here: ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes it is.).

Comment: Thanks. I am new to databases so I am trying to figure the design on my own, but I want to implement best practice too so I will switch it from a comma delimited string to its own table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work like this...

```
query.where('employee.dayswillwork SIMILAR TO  :days', {
        days: `%(${days.split(',').join('|')})%`,
      });
```